# pyspark - Join two RDDs - Missing third column

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, rdd

I'm very new at Pyspark please take in consideration :)

Basically I've this two textfiles:

file1:

```
  1,9,5
  2,7,4
  3,8,3
```

file2:

```
 1,g,h
 2,1,j
 3,k,i
```

And the Python code:

```
file1 = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/training/file1.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(","))

file2 = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/training/file2.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

Now doing this join:

```
join_file = file1.join(file2)
```

I was hoping to get this:

```
(1,(9,5),(g,h))
(2,(7,4),(i,j))
(3,(8,3),(k,1))
```

However, I am getting a different result:

```
(1, (9,g))
(3, (8,k))
(2, (7,1))
```

Am I missing any parameter on Join?

Thanks!

Comment: Hope is not a strategy. You need to have k, v tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
file1 = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/f1.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1:])))
file2 = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/f2.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1:])))
join_file = file1.join(file2)
join_file.collect()
```

returns with Unicode u':

```
Out[3]: 
[(u'2', ([u'7', u'4'], [u'1', u'j'])),
 (u'1', ([u'9', u'5'], [u'g', u'h'])),
 (u'3', ([u'8', u'3'], [u'k', u'i']))]
```